# Can I submit widget to Apple Store without iOS app?

Tags: ios, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

Can I submit widget (Today Extension) to Apple Store without iOS app? Only widget? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, widgets are part of apps and can not standalone.